# Opening new tab for process in ConEmu using 'start ...'

Tags: conemu

I'm trying to run a command using the Windows 'start' command while in a ConEmu tab and want it to just create a new tab instead of launching another terminal window.

For instance, if I'm in tab 1 of ConEmu and type 'start ping', I'd like that to open a new tab in the same ConEmu window instead of launching a separate window. I know I can use the -new_console but I thought there might be a way to hook it automatically. I thought I had it configured this way before but can't seem to find the correct settings. I tried entering 'start.exe' in the 'Default term | hooked executables' area but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended, use `-new_console` instead. `start` is not a real command, it's a keyword of cmd.exe and its processing is rather rough.

However

1. Open Settings/Features
2. Turn on "Process start".

Have you even tried to find the option?

Comment: That was it. Yes I did try to find it as I thought I had used that option before but it was buried where I didn't expect. Thanks regardless.